# Obtener datos JSON con GSON en Java

Tags: java, json, gson

Necesito obtener los datos `progress` y `tres` (ver ejemplo más abajo) pero no sé cómo.

Además en algunas ocasiones deberé recuperar más datos del tipo `class` sin saber de antemano cuantos serán.

Estoy mirando ejemplos del uso de GSON pero no lo consigo. ¿Alguna idea o documentación que pueda mirar? Muchas gracias.

**El código JSON es el siguiente:**

```js
{
    "images": [
        {
            "classifiers": [
                {
                    "classifier_id": "clasif",
                    "name": "nombre",
                    "classes": [
                        {
                            "class": "progress",
                            "score": 0.770309
                        },
                        {
                            "class": "tres",
                            "score": 0.599846
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "image": "imagen.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "images_processed": 1,
    "custom_classes": 6
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considera el siguiente ejemplo sacado de la documentacion de [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#object-examples):

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  private transient int value3 = 3;
  BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}

// Serialization
BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);  

// ==> json is {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}

// Deserialization
BagOfPrimitives obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, BagOfPrimitives.class);
// ==> obj2 is just like obj
```

En tu caso debes crear una clase de java que contenga los atributos definidos en el json y luego invocar `new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, TuClase.class)`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero sigo teniendo dudas, en mi caso con crear una clase Class como la siguiente serviría o necesito también una clase Classifiers donde guarde el contenido de  ese array de JSON para recorrerlo y coger todos los datos de tipo class? Muchas gracias

Comment: Necesitas crear todas las classes necesarias para modelar ese json, en tu caso son 4: class, classifier, image y aquella que contiene todo. En general cada vez que ves un par se llaves `{}` es un objeto que debe tener una contraparte java